# Problem installing Turi Create on WSL on Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt

I have installed Ubuntu on WSL for Turi Create, but when I start with:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

... I get the error:

```
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source"
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer:*

```
sudo apt update
```

Then install.

*More explanation:*

If you try to install *any* package *immediately* after install Ubuntu on WSL, you'll see either:

```
Package <package_name> is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

And/or:

```
E: Package '<package_name>' has no installation candidate
```

This is because the apt cache hasn't been populated yet.  To save bandwidth when downloading and installing Ubuntu on WSL, the package lists aren't populated by default.  An initial `sudo apt update` is *required* on apt-based distributions on WSL.

But as a general general rule, after installing any Debian-based distribution, it's recommended to `sudo apt update` as the first thing you do.  Otherwise, you'll likely get installation errors since packages and URLs in the cache change frequently.

Example - From a fresh Ubuntu install on WSL:

```bash
> sudo apt install python3-pip
[sudo] password for ntd:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate

> sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

... output trimmed

> sudo apt install python3-pip

... installs as expected
```